# play audio from object variable python

Tags: python-3.x, object, audio, text-to-speech

I had been trying to make a tts & stt python program in python 3.
I actually did it stt by google and tts too, because its the most natural tts I could find. Now I have a problem with playing that audio if I give the program a text gtts (google text to speech), change it to an object variable that needs to be played. How can I have it play the audio from an object variable in python 3.5.2?

I tried the sounddevice module but it just doesn't work in the way I need.

That is the function I'm using right now, but I want to avoid saving the file because it takes much time.

```
def say(TEXT , LANGUAGE = "en"):
#Speaks the text
   tts = gTTS(text=TEXT, lang=LANGUAGE)#converting the text
    print("SAVING...")
    tts.save("tmp.mp3")
    mixer.init()
    print("Speaking...")
    mixer.music.load('tmp.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    sleep(2)
    os.remove("tmp.mp3")
```

UPDATE

Also, how do I set the `os.remove()` to delete the *tmp.mp3* file after it is done, because that made a problem in case of saving the file?
Found a solution for that by playing the .mp3 file by terminal execute command so it have to be finished before proceeding to the rest of the remove line